# Cannot set the var i when returning up the chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var i = -1;
$('.rightBtn a').click(function(){

        --i; // this part works..

        if(i == -z){
            $(".homeSlider").css("margin-left", 0);
            $('.homeSlider').animate({
                marginLeft: '-='+$(window).width()
            }, function(){
                var i = -1; // this is where its not working    
                alert(i);   // alerts it correct at -1
                return i;   // this doesn't return it?

            });
            return i;
        } else {
            $('.homeSlider').animate({
                marginLeft: '-='+$(window).width()
            });
        return i;   
        }
        return i;
    //}
});
```

Am I just forgetting something? Also, say for the sake of the argument var z = 5

Comment: This strange piece of code would be easier to read if it were properly formated `-.-`

Comment: It's a chunk of javascript.. for some reason i thought the line i=-1; was illegal.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning `i` without there being anything to receive it. Set the value, don't return it.

Basically you're passing `i` back to the HTML. HTML is stupid. It doesn't know what to do with  it.

Comment: However, when I remove the returns and it hits the z value, I have it setting it to -1, but when I watch the expressions in firebug it just keeps going to -5 -6 -7

Answer (score 3):

```
            var i = -1; // this is where its not working
```

That's because you are creating a new variable and you're losing the original scope.  Try this instead:

```
            i = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, there are lots of things wrong here:

1. The `.animate()` function is asynchronous so it returns BEFORE the completion function runs so the completion function has no effect on the return value from your click function.
2. The return value from the click function is used to decide whether click propagation should continue or not and it should be a Boolean.
3. The local variable inside your completion function is overriding access to your global.  Usually, you don't want a local and global variable with the same name.
4. The return value from the completion function is not used for anything so returning your local copy of `i` there isn't doing anything.

I don't think you understand how asynchronous functions work.  When you call animate, it starts the animation and returns immediately.  The value of i will not have been changed yet by the completion callback.  Thus, when it returns, it will return the value of the global `i`.

Sometime later the completion function for the animation will get called.  In that function you are declaring a new local variable named, `i`, settings it's value and return it.  But nothing happens with the return value from the completion function so that does nothing.  So, you animation completion function has no effect on the value of the global variable `i`.

Then, returning `i` from the click function probably isn't doing what you want to do there either.  The return value of the click function should be a Boolean and it's value determines whether click propagation continues or not.  You return(false) to stop click propagation.  So returning the value of `i` from the click function is also having no effect on the global variable.

Lastly, it's usually an undesirable practice to have a global variable and a local variable with the same name.  It will be easy to confuse the two and not realize which is being affected by any given piece of code.  The local variable supercedes so when you declare a local variable with `var i;` and then assign to it with `i = -1;`, you are assigning only to the local variable and not affected the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining i locally in the call back.
Change it to:

```
function(){                 
   i = -1; 
   alert(i);   // alerts it correct at -1                 
   return i;   // this doesn't return it?              
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing var i twice in the same scope. Also, you're returning i, with nothing accepting it.